# Make $http requests with a URL stored on a .JSON

Tags: angularjs, http

I have some $http requests on my code like :

```
$http.get('http://test/api/ams/v1_0/courses')
```

and I want to put the URL http://test/api/ams/v1_0/courses on a .JSON, to have a lot of URLS stored, so if I need change one, I only need to go to the JSON config file, anyone knows how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like browserify, you can do something like this in your js file.

```
var config = require('./configs/config');
```

Your json file would look like so;

```
var config = {
    url : 'http://example.com'
};

module.exports = config;
```

Where config is a .json file, and the extension is not needed. You could then access this with usual object notation like config.url;

```
So $http(config.url + '/courses')...
```

You could then store something like

OR

Use Angular constant values, which in your case might be better still.

```
angular.module('App')
    .constant('API_ENDPOINT', {
        url: 'https://api.example.com'
    });
```

and the use API_ENDPOINT.url + 'courses' in your $http, just remember to include API_ENDPOINT in your dependency/include declarations where its needed.

You could also make API_ENDPOINT into a more complete object, and call it CONFIG and set several values inside.

It's your choice as to whether you use constants or json, but I tend to use constants myself.

Please name the constant value in all caps, as thats convention, but it will work regardless of case.

Answer (score 0):

something like this in the controller -

```
self.getData = $http.get('path').then(function success(a, b) {
    self.data = a;
}, function error(a, b) {
    self.data = false;
});
```